# VNC allocating a different IP to RaspberryPi3b

Tags: raspberry-pi, vnc

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi to my laptop using VNC server (RealVNC) but everytime I boot it up, it allocates a different IP to the device so it gets difficult to connect to the device because then I have to connect it to an HDMI display to see what's there on Pi's desktop and to see the IP that the VNC has been allocating. Suggest some measures to stick to a permanent IP.

Comment: Whats the matter of VNC in this case?

Comment: VNC is needed to use my laptop screen as a desktop for Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DHCP server serving the IP based on the MAC address.
It's as simple as that.